# How to remove thick white border on the top end and bottom end of android spinner?

Tags: android, react-native

I have built my app using react-native and there is a picker component in it. I have styled it using styles.xml but there is a white thick border on both ends of the dorpdown which I want to remove. I have tried almost everything - even setting both padding and margin to 0 but the top and bottom white thick border don't disappear. Can somebody point out how to remove them?

[image]

My Code:  /res/values/styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
  <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItem</item>
  <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/SpinnerDropDownItem</item>
</style>

<style name="SpinnerItem" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">>
  <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
  <item name="android:textSize">18dp</item>
</style>

<style name="SpinnerDropDownItem" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18dp</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/mydivider</item>
</style>
```

Code at res/drawable/mydivider.xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#29A1C9" />
    <corners android:radius="0.5dp" />
    <stroke
        android:color="#FFFFFF"
        android:width="0.1dp" />
</shape>
```

React native picker code:

```
 <Picker
      style={{color: darkTextColor, marginLeft:12}}
      ref={this.refId()}
      selectedValue={this.props.application.typeOfBusiness}
      onValueChange={(toi) => this.onUpdate('typeOfBusiness', toi)}>
      {typeOfBusinessLabels.map((val)=> <Picker.Item key={val} label={val} value={val}/>)}
 </Picker>`
```

Comment: try to add  `android:popupBackground = #29A1C9` property to your spinner

Comment: post your spinner in .xml layout @Abhishek Nalin

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki No it doesn't work even after adding popupBackground

Comment: @Anantham I posted all the styling code. Rest of the code is in JS.  I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is probably a bit late for you, but after running into the same issue and searching everywhere I was left with the choice of giving up, or going through all background properties to see if I could find it.

Luckily I didn't give up, as the first property I tried was `colorBackgroundFloating`. This property seems to control the background of all floating components

> Default color of background imagery for floating components, ex. dialogs, popups, and cards.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr#colorBackgroundFloating